# How do I set the extra field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here are the models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :positions

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :users, :through => :positions

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id, :regular_user
end
```

And my schema

```
create_table "positions", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
  t.boolean  "regular_user", :default => true
end
```

I have these params

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"id"=>"", "first_name"=>"some", "last_name"=>"name",
"phone_number"=>"4074615519", "email"=>"something@gmail.com", "active"=>"true", 
"company_ids"=>["186"], "role_ids"=>["2"], "notification_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}}
```

THE PROBLEM I am running into is the positions.regular_user is always true when i do

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

or the

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
```

pprobably because it defaults to true.... But i need to change to false if role_ids is > 3

any ideas on how to change the default flag

Answer (score 0):

Use a `before_save` callback to set the `role_id` attribute. Example:

```
class User
  before_save :set_role_id

  private

  def set_role_id
    if role_id > 3
      self.regular_user = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I dont think i can do that because self is the user and not the position

Answer (score 0):

Use `before_save` filter:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id, :regular_user

  before_save :update_regular_flag

private
  def update_regular_flag
    self.regular_user = (role_id <= 3)
  end
end
```